# How to set vite config to remove index file sunbfolder while mutlple entry point

Tags: vue.js, configuration, vite, entry-point, index.html

I am using vite with vuejs i have multiple entry points my issue I am getting a extra subfolder as login like below (my current folder structure).

├─ my-app/
│  ├─ dist
├─ login
├─ login
├─index.html

Actually I want like this,

├─ my-app/
│  ├─ dist
├─ login
├─index.html

Below is the code in vite.config.login.ts,

```
    import { resolve } from 'path';
    import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
    import Vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
    import VueRouter from 'unplugin-vue-router/vite';
    export default defineConfig({
      base: '/', // Set the base path for assets
      plugins: [Vue(), VueRouter()],
      build: {
        outDir: 'dist/login',
        rollupOptions: {
          input: resolve("./login/index.html", ""),
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for outDir you can have `dist` instead of `dist/login`